# The listview, made with SimpleCursorAdapter is not refreshing after deleting an entry from the Context menu. Below is the java code

Tags: android, android-listview, refresh

The listview(lv) is made up with SimpleCursorAdapter and it represents the three textviews which are fethed from the database.

I've added the notifyDataSetChanged() after delete operations as well, but its not working. I've even added the invalideViews().

I'd be grateful for your assistance.

```
package com.snm.anand.whoowsme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class homepage extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    MyDatabase mdb = new MyDatabase(this);
    Cursor c;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
    public void onCreate(final Bundle SavedInstances) {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstances);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
        mdb.open();

        c = mdb.getemp();
        String [] from = {"ename","enumber","eamnt"};
        int [] to = {R.id.textView3,R.id.textView4,R.id.textView5};
        sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item, c, from, to);
        lv.setAdapter(sca);
        sca.notifyDataSetChanged();

        registerForContextMenu(lv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Click to delete the entry.");
        menu.add("Delete");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getTitle()=="Delete"){
            Log.w("myapp", "dele");
            int position = item.getItemId();
            long pid = lv.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
            mdb.empdelete(pid);
            c = mdb.getemp();
            lv.invalidateViews();
            sca.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.addNewPerson:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, addNewPerson.class));
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY, i know it is deprecated but you are using deprecated SCA ctor anyway...

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that? I'm newbie to Android, I'd appreciate if you could tell me that too.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY